# Communication (interprocess) between applications

Tags: c#, client-server, interprocess

I'm about to write a "server" application that is responsible to talk with external hardware. The application shall handle requests from clients. The clients send a message to the server, and if the server is busy with doing stuff with the hardware the new messages shall be stored in a queue that will be processed later.

The client shall also be able to cancel a request (if it is in the server's queue.). When the server application is finished with the hardware it shall be able to send the result back to the client that requested the job.

The server and client applications may or may not be on the same PC. All development is done in .NET (C#) 2005.

What is the best way to solve this communication problem?

[MSMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing)? [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)? [WCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)? [Remoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting)? Other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Remoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting)

If all development is done in .NET 2005, Remoting is the best way to go.

Comment: Remoting is dead - use WCF with NetNamedPipeBinding instead!

Comment: I will go with remoting. Remoting seem too fit my needs very well. If I could use .Net 3.0 then I would have picked WCF, but that is not an option right now. I will on the other hand prepare so much I can for a migration in the future (Migrating .NET Remoting to WCF: http://blogs.msdn.com/mattavis/archive/2005/10/10/479280.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s, remoting might be dead, but so is VS 2005 (atleast according to M$). If you develop on VS 2008/.NET3.5 or the upcoming 2010/.NET4, WCF might be a choice to consider. Otherwise, I prefer to stick with Remoting...

Comment: 2005 supports WCF via an extension. Remoting would not be my first choice.

Comment: Perhaps it is time for an update? But **************** ***without*** **************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). Old content can be qualified-e.g., *"Before 2010, Remoting was the preferred solution, but then..."*

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can use .NET 3.0 or greater then you probably want to WCF as the communications channel - the interface is consistent but it will allow you to use an appropriate transport mechanism depending on where the client and server are in relation to each other - so you can choose to use SOAP or MSMQ or a binary format or others as appropriate (and can roll your own if needed). It also covers the need for two way communication.

Queuing the messages at the server should probably be regarded as a separate problem - especially given the need to remove queued messages.

Comment: Use NetNamedPipe for on-machine interprocess communication - your best choice!

Answer (score 1):

If clients and server processes are on the same machine, I think [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#In_Windows) will give you the fastest raw byte transfer rate.

If the processes are across different machines, you'd need to use *sockets*-based approach.

Remoting is reportedly very slow. Based on the target OSes that you're planning to deploy the solution on, you could have options like WCF et al. However, the overhead of these protocols is something you may want to look at while deciding.

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ would make some sense, though there are then security and deployment considerations.  You could look at a service bus (such s NServiceBus or MassTransit) and there's also SQL Server Service Broker that could help (and can also be used by a service bus as the transport).

WCF would be another thing to look at, however that's really the across-network transport, so you'd probably still want the WCF calls to put a message on the server queue.

I don't recommend remoting, because it's hard to maintain a separation of concerns, and before you know it you're developing a really chatty interface without realising it.  Remote calls are expensive in relative terms, so you should be trying to keep the messages fairly coarse-grained.  WCF would be my recommendation.  Not least because you can set it up to use a HTTP transport and avoid a lot of deployment and security headache.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework provides several ways to communicate with objects in different application domains, each designed with a particular level of expertise and flexibility in mind. For example, the growth of the Internet has made XML Web services an attractive method of communication, because XML Web services are built on the common infrastructure of the HTTP protocol and SOAP formatting, which uses XML. These are public standards, and can be used immediately with current Web infrastructures without worrying about additional proxy or firewall issues.

Not all applications should be built using some form of XML Web service, however, if only because of the performance issues related to using SOAP serialization over an HTTP connection.

[Choosing Communication Options in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8119f66k(VS.80).aspx) helps you decide which form of interobject communication you want for your application.